# c++ combine erase and remove string

Tags: c++, string

I saw someone use this line to remove white spaces from string stored in a vector, but I fail to understand the reason for using erase and remove this way?
The second question: how can I, instead of only removing white spaces, remove anything that is not a 'num' or a '-' ?

this is not the full code, it is only a snippet, will not compile. the vector simply contains raw strings of a text file, the strings were comma delimited, currently the strings could contain any possible char except the comma.

```
vector <string> vecS;
ifstream vecStream;
while(vecStream.good()) {
 vecS.resize(i+1);
 getline(vecStream, vecS.at(i), ',');
 vector <string> vecS;          
 vecS.at(i).erase(remove( vecS.at(i).begin(), vecS.at(i).end(), ' '), vecS.at(i).end());
 i++
}
```

EDIT; added more code, hope this is clearer now

Comment: Did you know you can format code as code? When you edit your question, look for the orange ? It will give you some help (you can also hover over the other buttons too).

Comment: Please post **real code**. The current code won't compile. With hypothetical code guessing at the rationale of the real code that served as inspiration, becomes … a guessing game.

Comment: @Samuel yeah i edited my question and lost the code formatting, you were faster than me to fix it

Comment: I'm confused: **both** `vecS`s are empty.

Comment: One question per question please. This isn't a chat room.

Comment: -1: Not real code, not valid syntax, what on earth is that `ifstream` doing there?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I fail to understand the reason for using erase and remove this
>   way?

`std::remove` basically rearranges the sequence so that the elements which are **not** to be removed are all shifted to the beginning of the sequence - a past-the-end iterator for that part, and effectively the new end of the sequence, is then returned.

There is absolutely no need for a file stream in that snippet though:

```
vector <string> vecS;
// Do something with vecS

for( auto& s : vecS )   
    s.erase( remove_if( std::begin(s), std::end(s), 
                        [](char c){ return std::isspace(c); }), // Use isspace instead, that recognizes all white spaces
             std::end(s) );
```

Comment: thanks :) how can extend this to remove everything that is not a number or a '-' ?

Comment: @Molegrammer In the lambda, instead of just using `isspace`, add the appropriate conditions.

Comment: @Molegrammer So the condition is `!std::isdigit(c) && c != '-'`

Comment: would this also remove white spaces ?